# sed command is throwing error : char 80: unknown command: `*'

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace string in property file using sed command.
Property file has below entry 
`com.rs.TestScopeService.resourceScopesA./**={TestAPI}`

I want to replace this entry with below string 
`#com.rs.TestScopeService.resourceScopesB./**={TestAPI}`

my sed command is --
`sed -i '/com.rs.TestScopeService.resourceScopesA./**={TestAPI}/c\#com.rs.TestScopeService.resourceScopesB./**={TestAPI}' /Users/Desktop/test.properties`

Above cmd throws error : `` sed: -e expression #1, char 80: unknown command: `*' ``.

Please help me in correcting the command to avoid error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go around the `*` issues by adding a backshash before each `*`.  Do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

originalstring="com.rs.TestScopeService.resourceScopesA./**={TestAPI}"

echo "$originalstring" | sed 's%^\(com\.rs\.TestScopeService\.resourceScopes\)A\(\./\*\*={TestAPI}\)$%#\1B\2%'
```

- I used character `%` as the `sed` `s` separator.
- Any character `sed` uses as delimiter or operator must be backslashed to let `sed` know to treat it as text.  Here, `.`, `*` have to.
- Reversely, backslash the parenthesis so `sed` will know they are for grouping, not matching.
- `^`: starts with...
- `$`: ends with...
- `\1` and `\2` are used to build the result string.  `\1` is the content of the first parenthesis (`com\.rs\.TestScopeService\.resourceScopes`), `\2` the second (`\./\*\*={TestAPI}`).

Comment: Thank you so much @nic3500 , that worked perfectly. Can you please also let me know the command to how do I replace this in file.

Comment: Liek this `sed -i -e 's/few/asd/' hello.txt`